# Perforce - p4 sync command is not working

Tags: perforce

I am unable to run a perforce command on windows commandline or powershell due to an error.

I did some actions on the UI and got the corresponding command perforce command which is -

```
p4 sync -f //MyFolder/Code/Project1...#head
```

This gives an error -
MyFolder is a depot, not a client.

Why does this error occur and how do I run a perforce command ?

Comment: What is the *actual exact command* you're running?  It sounds like you might have a simple typo in the command you're running, so if your actual depot name isn't `MyFolder`, please copy and paste the *actual exact command* and the *actual exact error message* that you're getting at the command line.  If you can include your client view (`p4 client -o`) that may also be relevant.

Comment: @samwise - I am used to Git and new to perforce. I dont know how to do perforce actions via commandline. How do I specify a depot instead of MyFolder ? When i run your command, I still get the same error - MyFolder is a depot, not a client.

Comment: OH.  You set your client name equal to the name of a depot.  (Or vice versa?)  Lol.  Took me a second, I don't think I've ever seen that error before.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `P4CLIENT` variable.  If you have a client workspace already set up, use that.  Depots and clients share a namespace, so client names can't overlap with depot names (that's the error you're getting).

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=MasterJoe-ws
```

Note that the default `P4CLIENT` is the name of your client host, which is usually a suitably unique name (unless you've deliberately named your depot to match your client host, or vice versa).

If you don't already have a client workspace, then after you've set up P4CLIENT, create the actual client workspace:

```
p4 client
```

Then you can sync the workspace:

```
p4 sync
```

Comment: Thank you samwise. For readers, P4CLIENT will hold the name of your perforce workspace.